# python re match string in a file

Tags: python

I want to match all the lines in a file either starting with `0D` and has 15 `Characters` or just having 15 digits. How  can i do this

```
p_number = re.compile(r'(\d{15})')
f=open(infile)
for l in f:
  aa=re.findall(p_number,l)
  if aa > 0:
     print aa
f.close()
```

`EDIT`

If only the pattern is in the starting of the line.

Comment: re.findall returns a list, so comparing it to 0 is meaningless. What is your error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find matches *only* at the beginning of the line, use [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match). This regex matches all non-whitespace characters if the `0D` prefix is present; if you want to match fewer characters, let me know.

```
>>> p_number = re.compile(r'(0D[\S]{13}|\d{15})')
>>> for s in ['0Dfannawhoopowe foo', 
              'foo 012345678901234', 
              '012345678901234 foo']:
...     match = p_number.match(s)
...     if match:
...         print match.groups()
... 
('0Dfannawhoopowe',)
('012345678901234',)
```

For a sense of the difference between `match`, `search`, and `findall`, see the following examples.

`findall` (naturally) finds all occurrences of the match:

```
>>> for s in ['0Dfannawhoopowe foo', 
              'foo 012345678901234', 
              '012345678901234 foo']:
...     match = p_number.findall(s)
...     if match:
...         print match
... 
['0Dfannawhoopowe']
['012345678901234']
['012345678901234']
```

`search` finds an occurrence of the string anywhere in the string, not just at the beginning.

```
>>> for s in ['0Dfannawhoopowe foo', 
              'foo 012345678901234', 
              '012345678901234 foo']:
...     match = p_number.search(s)
...     if match:
...         print match.groups()
... 
('0Dfannawhoopowe',)
('012345678901234',)
('012345678901234',)
```

Comment: I am not able to match the following 0D57000000FFrsy

Comment: You shouldn't be able to match that. It doesn't contain 15 digits. You said "either starting with 0D and has 15 digits or just having 15 digits," which I interpreted to mean strings like this: `0Dddddddddddddddd` or like this: `ddddddddddddddd`. The example in your comment is neither. Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
with open(infile) as f:
 print re.findall('^(0D.{15}|\d{15})$',f.read(),re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this with regular expressions, of course you can do it:

```
with open(infile) as f:
  for l in f:
     if re.match('(0D)?[0-9]{15}', l):
       print l
```

But you can solve the task without regular expressions at all:

```
with open(infile) as f:
  for l in f:
     if (len(l) == 15 and l.is_digit()) or (l[:2]='0D' and len(l)==17 and l[2:].is_digit()):
       print l
```

Comment: And how to check that the line should start with one such expression or else proceed to next line

Comment: @Levon: That's right; i didn't noted that condition; thank you!

Comment: @Rajeev: that makes `match` automatically

Comment: I am not able to match the following 0D57000000FFrsy

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel with `only_digits`. `'15'.isdigit() == True`; `'15f'.isdigit() == False`.